# SRAM works with short read cycles, fails with longer ones

Tags: fpga, sram

I observe a rather weird behavior of an [IS62WV51216BLL-55TLI](http://www.issi.com/WW/pdf/62WV51216ALL.pdf) SRAM chip connected to an FPGA. When I run it with the shortest read cycles possible, it works as expected:

[image]
<sup>(here, I read the expected value 0xCF9C3063. One tick is 6.25 ns)</sup>

However, when I try to use longer read cycles, it mysteriously fails:
[image]
<sup>(here, I read the value 0x136000D0 instead of 0x1360EC9F. One tick is 6.25 ns)</sup>

As you can see, the right data appears on the data bus at some point, but is quickly replaced by a bogus value. This happens sporadically at a different address every time, and re-reading the same address a second time works fine:

[image]
<sup>(here, I read the value 0x18E06439 the first time, and the expected value 0x18E0E71F the second time)</sup>

Does anybody have a reasonable explanation for this? Is there something wrong with my read cycle? Here's the read cycle from the datasheet above, for reference:
[image]

All my diagrams were made with SignalTap (logic analyzer built into FPGA) running at 160MHz. All output pins of the SRAM controller are registered:

```
// ** Output Pin tcm_address_out 

reg                       tcm_address_outen_reg;     

always@(posedge clk) begin
 if( reset ) begin
   tcm_address_outen_reg <= 'b0;
 end
 else begin
   tcm_address_outen_reg <= 'b1;
 end
 end             


reg [ 19 : 0 ] tcm_address_out_reg;   

 always@(posedge clk) begin
 tcm_address_out_reg   <= tcs_tcm_address_out[ 19 : 0 ];
  end


assign  tcm_address_out[ 19 : 0 ] = tcm_address_outen_reg ? tcm_address_out_reg : 'z ;
```

The `tcm_address_out` signal is then connected to the `sram_addr` pins seen on the diagrams above, which are in turn connected to the `A0`-`A18` pins of the SRAM IC. Other pins are connected in a similar manner. The length of wires/traces between an FPGA pin and a SRAM pin is about 10 cm. The SRAM IC has 1uF + 100nF ceramic caps between GND and VDD pins of both sides.

PS. I have tried to keep \$\overline{CS}\$ asserted the whole time, which didn't improve things. I have also tried a modification where \$\overline{OE}\$ is asserted 12.5ns after \$\overline{CS}\$ and is deasserted for 12.5ns between consecutive reads (while keeping \$\overline{CS}\$). That didn't help:

[image]

Comment: Show us the code. I had hard time with similar stuff, solved with multiple buffers. In any case don't trust signal tap, probably there is more on lines than it sees.

Comment: I don't know, whatever is relevant (and not too long).

Comment: Why OE comes at same moment as CS?

Comment: Try CS first (not all time) then oe. Like in datasheet.

Comment: The point is very simple. If it doesn't work, do exactly like they say. If it still doesn't work, look for a bigger mistake. Crap on memory output may be a symptom of missing decoupling capacitor, bad voltage, fake components, whatever. But to go to investigate it that way you first need to do everything by the book. Don't forget, sometimes datasheet may be not 100% complete, especially for memory which is normally used with a CPU, so just a tiny minority of engineers read it's datasheet

Comment: Well...first off the waveform captures are NOT like the data sheet chip timing diagram in that you are changing the address values during the chip select cycle. Just pointing that out as a difference despite the fact that SRAM read cycles should work just fine from just the address changing to valid data after the tAA access time. I am pretty much on the page with Gregory here in that the problem is most likely something not showing in these timing captures. Could be power surge or droop to the SRAM chip, ground bounce, or even some type of transient contention on the SRAM_DATA pins.

Comment: Many many years ago I worked for weeks on an SRAM reading problem on a board that had a bank of SRAMs that were being buffered to an 8085 data bus through a bi-directional 8-bit bus buffer. It turned out that the problem was due to the direction control of the buffer pointing toward the SRAMs by about 2-3 nsec at the end of the cycle just before the read cycle data was going to go tri-state.

Comment: @MichaelKaras I'm reluctant to copy the whole datasheet in my question, but if you look at page 8 you'll see a diagram where the address is changed during the read cycle. And by the way my problem never occurs during the second read (which is done without cycling \$\overline{CS}\$), only during the first read, when \$\overline{OE}\$ has just being asserted.

Comment: I was responding to what was posted. I did say that reads from address changing should also work. Do you possibly have signal integrity problems on your address lines? Logic analyzer traces will tend to hide that.

Comment: There's just too little information to go on. You've left out the circuit, and the bus interface HDL...stuff that may be beyond question to yourself but is in doubt to outsiders like us. SignalTap is clock-sampled data only, not faster intermediates so not much use. Sorry but there it is.

Comment: @MichaelKaras The weird thing is that the issue occurs during slow read cycles, which take ~150ns. That's only about 6-7 MHz. The wires between the FPGA and the SRAM IC are maybe 10 cm long, I believe transients have plenty of time to settle.

Comment: @TonyM I didn't post any of the HDL because I believe I have isolated the problem to the SRAM interface. If I had a problem with my Verilog code, wouldn't it show up in the diagrams? The circuit is trivial: every `sram_x` signal is connected to corresponding `x` pin on the SRAM. And wouldn't the transients settle during those 150 ns?

Comment: Let me give you a little bit of experienced advice, with your indulgence then. The problem has such a likelihood of being in the bit you know isn't where the problem lies. The bits you trust are the bits to distrust. Have you checked the FPGA pin-out settings? First port of call. Besides that, no-one can second guess you if you got bits you trust and bits you don't. Good luck with it, will leave you to it.

Comment: @TonyM Sorry, I couldn't understand that. Do you mean that there's a very good chance that my SRAM is working fine and the issue is somewhere else?

Comment: As an experiment, make CS and OE transition at different times (one internal clock apart should do it); I have had unusual results from *some* devices (both SRAMs and FPGAs) where those signals transitioned at the same time.

Comment: @PeterSmith Thanks for the suggestion. Check out the last diagram, I think this is exactly what I have tried. Same result, unfortunately.

Comment: Why ARE you changing address mid-cycle anyway? I'm really not convinced this is not your issue.

Comment: Is it possible to guess what other locations (addresses) of the SRAM where the wrongly read data is coming from? Like in your last diagram where the 0x620 shows up. Any idea what location that comes from?

Comment: You also say that the the traces from FPGA to the SRAM are 10cm long. That is long enough and the FPGA outputs have transition times that are fast enough where you probably and really should have 22 to 33 ohm resistors in series with each line at the FPGA outputs. Note that the SignalTap view of the SRAM signals are "isolated" from whatever is going on at the physical board level  and you will likely need to use the a regular oscilloscope to investigate the signals themselves at the SRAM to evaluate the SI (signal integrity) that I alluded to before.

Comment: I'd also be looking at signal levels. What the signaltap thinks is a 1 or 0 maybe different from that is SRAM thinks is a 1 or 0. Buiilt in analyzers only take you so far and only give you a view from within the chip. If everything else outside is working as you think they are good, if not, they can just lead you down the wrong path.

Comment: Continued: Ships engineer "I don't understand it captain, engine is going full speed but we are not moving".... Bosun's mate... "Hey captain. what do you want me to do with this propeller I found out back.."

Comment: I'd strongly suspect a dry joint somewhere on the address bus. Pin only capacitively  coupled to the signal line...

Comment: Despite the name, high-density static RAMs do use internal timing generators to control things like sense amplifier precharge, etc. These are driven by the edges on the control lines. Note that the datasheet states that the test conditions assume transition times of 5 ns or less. This is something you'll want to verify in your setup -- slow edges, or edges with a lot of ringing could produce the symptoms you're seeing.

Comment: @Trevor, OP is changing the address during the cycle because it's a 2-beat read i.e. the RAM data bus is half the width of his reading data width. That's all fine. I just think, as we can only see a small part of the picture here, the attention's on one particular piece of data and there's so many unknowns. If it was me, I get to this stage and check everything: FPGA pin assignments, RAM datasheet against symbol, clock, rails, all bus timings etc. This sanity check takes an hour and can save loads of time. (Sorry earlier post read blunt though accurate, OP, typed from a very sunny castle :-) )

Comment: @TonyM Since the SRAM works with different timing settings, I'd say pin assignments are certainly fine. Unfortunately I don't have a sufficiently fast scope at home to look at the real signals, but it sounds like Dave has a point: this may be a glitch due to ringing. Too bad my FPGA has no slew rate settings.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev, your posted test showed reads at different speeds from different addresses - the only difference wasn't speed. I could repeat it all day but it doesn't matter: it's valuable to be certain - dead certain - of the baseline, take that from long experience :-) (I rarely play the 'old soldier' line!) Takes little time, rules out the evil thing in fault-finding: suppositions. Incidentally, ringing would be worse with fast reads than slow ones, not the other way round. Post the answer when you find it, good luck for a quick job :-)

Comment: @TonyM Oh I totally agree with you, I was just pointing out it  bears the characteristics of bad joint and the internal analyser wont help him with that.

Comment: @Trevor I have checked all pins with my multimeter, and also tried a second IC sample, with the same results.

Comment: @DaveTweed You were right - adding source termination resistors to the pins driving the SRAM helped. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Dmitry, in order to get the solution to your issue, you will need systemically troubleshoot it. TonyM, Trevor, Dave, Michael and Gregory provided several guesses, which need to be systemically qualified within your design. I will provide some summary below for you:

- your board is having some FPGA, with IS62WV51216BLL-55TLI chip connected to it through 10 centimeter long tracks;
- no information on power routing, or power decoupling is available;
- you shown the code selecting the address, no information is available how you sample the data into FPGA design.
- no board pictures are available, we can not see design of your board and how it is made.

Let's look into the configuration:

```
always@(posedge clk) begin
 if( reset ) begin
```

Your analyzer readings are missing reset signal. You will have to prove that `reset` signal is always low when issue exhibits.

Now let's look into diagrams. As you noticed value changes E0A0 -> ECA0 -> EC9F -> 00D0, with change to 00D0 happening inside the read cycle, and being an issue you report. This SRAM is not registered in its input and I/O pins, thus if it starts outputting some wrong signals, several issues may occur:

- power issue. If there would be intermittent power problem, RAM chip would anyway end up with right value being read as it has unregistered inputs. You can try to increase read cycle even more, to see if value changes again from 00D0 to EC9F. If power would go bad completely, there would be data corruption in the RAM contents, as it does not happen (and second time you can read the correct data) I hardly believe it is power issue.
- control or address signal issue. Do you have pull-ups on the data lines? If you would have them, then inactivity will be read as FFFF, otherwise it can be read anything. I would recommend turning weak pull-ups on at the FPGA side. It is really hard to say what may happen to the control/address lines, as commentators pointed that what you have is how FPGA sees the situation, and not what really happens on the interconnect between FPGA and SRAM.

I would recommend you the following:

- turn weak pull-ups on on the data lines to ensure that if you have chip selection/out enable issues it is seen as FFFF on the bus;
- catch the buggy read cycle and halt the system, using logic probe seeing logic levels on the pins. For this you can fill RAM with some predefined content (e.g. 0001 - 0203 - 0405 - ...), and read addresses in loop until you get unexpected value, and halt clock when it happens. Using multimeter/logic probe measure voltages of all signals - control, data and address - to find out how it looks from the outside of FPGA.
- as people already said in comments, check physical connections. You take magnifier and look at each PCB joint, you use a needle putting it between chip's pins (if it is not BGA but TSOP) with some force to ensure that when you apply small force pins are not get torn off the pads (be very gentle not to bend pins and tear pads away!).

Comment: Thanks, I will try those things you mention (I didn't try weak pull-ups yet, and halting the clock). The primary suspect IMO is the ringing Dave has mentioned, so my next step would be to get the proto board to a lab with a decent scope. However, if that yields no results, I'll go through the whole list.